# Getting table names from PostGIS database in PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, postgresql

I would like to list the name of all tables of PostGIS in a given DB called DB-1 in PyQGIS.
I found this Q&A at Stack Oveflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418667/get-table-names-from-postgis-database-with-pyqgis

But it seems this solution doesn't work anymore when I try this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("BD-1");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("BD-1");
db.setUserName("postgres");
db.setPassword("postgres");
db.open();
names=db.tables( QSql.Tables)
print names
```

And the result is empty array :

```
[]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does it not work? Syntax error? Something not found? Only lists half the tables? Please edit the question and tell us what the problem is. What version of QGIS? Qt4 isn't supported in the latest, so maybe that's the problem and you need to use Qt5? How can we tell?

Comment: it seems to be syntax error, and I've edited my post and tried in PyQT5 but problems remains.

Comment: please tell us what the actual error is

Comment: The first error was a syntax error due to some spaces.. and now I've corrected it, it result an empty array. It seems something is wrong with my database name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find another approach, at least for recent QGIS 3 versions

```py
md = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres')

# Approach 1 without using existing connection
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "DB-1", "postgres", "postgres")
conn1 = md.createConnection(uri.uri(), {})
print(conn1.tables())
print([f'{i.schema()}.{i.tableName()}' for i in conn1.tables()])

# Approach 2 using existing connection
# (declared in "Data Source manager | PostgreSQL")
conn2 = md.createConnection('DB-1')
print(conn2.tables())
print([f'{i.schema()}.{i.tableName()}' for i in conn2.tables()])

# Get list of schema and table name excluding system tables
print([f'{i.schema()}.{i.tableName()}' for i in conn2.tables() if i.schema() not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')])
# Get list of table name excluding system tables
print([f'{i.tableName()}' for i in conn2.tables() if i.schema() not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')])
```

You can filter tables using first argument for schema name e.g `conn1.tables('schema_name')` and/or combined with the type of tables you want `conn1.tables('public', QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.Aspatial)`

Second argument can be amongst https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.html#af21b880041c38786e158ce1f564211b0 Second argument can be combined at it's based on flags mechanism.

Comment: at the moment the result looks like : [<QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.TableProperty: 'qgis_projects'>]
How can I get only the names ?

Comment: And also, when I do : print([f'{i.schema()}.{i.tableName()}' for i in conn2.tables()])
I get a lot of useless data that doesn't match witch schema.. Is there a way to have only the list of the names of tables (schema.tables) that appears in the schemas on the PostGIS windows?

Comment: Edited to filter to exclude system schemas

Comment: and about using this filter : print(conn1.tables('test2')) , I get   [<QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.TableProperty: 'point_topo'>, <QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.TableProperty: 'geography_columns'>, <QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.TableProperty: 'geometry_columns'>, <QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.TableProperty: 'qgis_projects'>, <QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.TableProperty: 'spatial_ref_sys'>]
How can I get only the name of tables?

Answer (score 3):

had to write `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")` My error was that I thought I had to write my DB name.

```
 from PyQt5.QtSql import *
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
        db.setHostName("localhost");
        db.setDatabaseName("DB-1");
        db.setUserName("postgres");
        db.setPassword("postgres");
        db.open();
        names=db.tables( QSql.Tables)
        print names
```